# Kafka new producer timeout

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using the new kafka producer client and set the timeout.ms property to 50 ms.

Here is the complete configuration used in the producer:

```
props.put("acks", "1");
props.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");
props.put("retries", "1");
props.put("batch.size", "16384");
props.put("client.id", "foo");
props.put("linger.ms", "0");
props.put("timeout.ms", "50");
```

The request average response time in some moments of high load is 4 seconds, but I don't get any timeout error.

Does Someone know how this timeout is calculated, when it begins to be counted and when it finishes? Is there a way to configure a timeout to start from the moment the producer's send method is called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new `timeout.ms` property works with the `ack` configuration of the producer. For example consider the following situation

```
ack = all
timeout.ms = 3000
```

In this case `ack = all` means that the leader will not respond untill it receives acknowledgement for the full set of in-sync replicas (ISR) and the maximum wait time to get this acknowledgement will be `3000 ms`. If it didn't receive the expected number of acknowledgements within the given time it will return an error.

Also note this property does not consider network latency.

From the doc page :

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the server will wait for acknowledgments from followers to meet the acknowledgment requirements the producer has specified with the acks configuration. If the requested number of acknowledgments are not met when the timeout elapses an error will be returned. This timeout is measured on the server side and does not include the network latency of the request.

So in your case with `ack=1` (I am not 100% sure about this and open to any correction if applicable) if the leader is not able to respond (after writing the record to its own log without awaiting full acknowledgement from all followers) within 50ms should throw an error.

Comment: This config doesn't exists on the new kafka producer, it says it will be ignored when I start the producer.

Comment: Agreed, the new producer configuration uses this instead of the old property, updated the answer accordingly

Comment: You are right, that's the expected behavior, but our problem is a little bit different. 
We are overloading kafka and some nodes stop answering (probably because GC), but the producer doesn't have a timeout on client side so it waits until the node is back to send the queued messages. There is a issue about that on kafka jira (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1788).

Comment: In Kafka 0.10.2.0 _timeout.ms_ is deprecated and new _request.timeout.ms_ is introduced.

Comment: I have a similar issue but request.timeout.ms property did not help me.

Answer (score 8):

In the new Kafka 2.0 Producer API, you can use one of the following properties : 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

See usage examples on https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

The timeout is now defined by the `max.block.ms` property.

Comment: Hello @Guigoz, i have a doubt. My doubt is: Once the `max.block.ms` is reached, for example 10000ms, can i say for sure that the producer will _stop trying_ to send to the topic? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jumping_monkey,

Sorry I've not actively used Kafka since 2018 so I can't say for sure, but the documentation says : "The threshold for time to block is determined by max.block.ms after which it throws a TimeoutException."

If an Exception is thrown, your kafka producer will throw this TimeoutException. 
Then, you will be able to catch it and do whatever you have to do (retry or fail/log for example).

Hope it answers your question :)

Comment: Hello @Guigoz, thanks a lot for getting back. Yea, i am treating like it's _killing_ the request(the blocking thread) 100%. Hopefully, i am (we are) right. And just curious, why did you stop using Kafka actively? Is there a better alternative? Cheers mate.

Comment: Hi @jumping_monkey. I'm just working on other projects which do not use Kafka. On more recent projects we prefer using rabbitmq for messaging purposes when we do not have high performance needs. We find it more easy to use and stable