# Apache Kafka Producer.send randomly hangs

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I was trying to get a basic kafka stream working, and I created a producer and used

```
producer.send(record).get()
```

to send a ProducerRecord to the kafka stream. It was hanging, so I changed a few config things and eventually it worked. I tried it again with the EXACT same code and EXACT same server configuration, and it hung. I tried it about 10 more times and it hung each time. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try adding `producer.close()`

Comment: Actually the producer is trying to connect to kafka, but looks like it's not able to connect. If you leave the program to continue executing you can find the producer throwing a Timeout exception for connecting to kafka.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468158/kafka-new-producer-timeout

Comment: It ended up being a server config issue, not an issue with my code.